# Is it possible to import a schma to Oracle 18c Express Edition from an Oracle 11g Standard Edition Dump file?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp, oracle-dump

I have a dump file (one schema, size is less than 1GB) which is created (Using EXPDP) from Oracle 11g standard edition (VERSION Parameter not used).

Is it possible to load this dump file to an Oracle Database 18c Express Edition using IMPDP?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, yes. Doesn't cost much to try it. If anything goes wrong, you'd just drop the user from your 18c XE database and start over.

Comment: Thank you for you comment,I'll try and update the same here